Pixel phones: good Google Camera app algorithm and LineageOS support
Pixel phones (both older Qualcomm and newer Google Tensor) are known for very good camera algorithm. What I have heard the camera chipset (hardware) is similar to other phones, but the algorithm is what makes quite significant difference.
Which part of the software stack is doing that algorithms? Is it only Pixel Camera app or is there some other firmware? I'm asking if I reinstall stock Android with LineageOS whether I loose this functionality.
Also, I suppose Pixel Camera app is installable on LineageOS.
I'm asking specifically about Google Pixel 5 (redfin) and 6 (oriole), but it can be considered as a general question about all Pixel phones.
I also suppose this is the only functionality I could use when migrating to LineageOS (I've had good experience with LineageOS support on other phones).

To my knowledge the important part is the Google camera app "GCam". Installing it on a non-official Google Pixel firmware like LineageOS is possible but not as simple as a regular app installation.

Is GCam a normal Android application, just not on google play? BTW I also found various third party apps: Google Camera Port
, GCam not from google (port for other phones).

Reddit thread answers at least gcam is not part of AOSP and most likely not Apache License or GPL license ("Because native gcam sells pixels, that's why, would be dumb to release it to everyone.") ports are pirated.

Google Camera app is on Google Play but only available for Pixel devices, thus it can only be installed as update.

@Robert But that should be installable on LineageOS (not app update but new installation), right?

The Google Camera from Play Store requires Android 14 + system feature android.hardware.camera.level.full (not all phones have this feature) and com.google.android.feature.GOOGLE_EXPERIENCE which is only present on Google Pixel firmware (and may be on some modded custom ROMS, but I doubt that it is present in official LineageOS builds.
